# SQL character escape error despite gsubbing

Tags: lua, mariadb

I'm using a common function to GSUB special characters and replace it with escaped characters but I'm still getting an SQL error almost as if it's not doing anything. When looking at the query given I notice two backslashes. Here is the function I'm using:

```
function escape_sqli(source)
    local replacements = { ['"'] = '\\"', ["'"] = "\\'" }
    return source:gsub( "['\"]", replacements ) -- or string.gsub( source, "['\"]", replacements )
end
```

This is the data I'm inputting: `You're`

This is part of the query after the GSUB: `"message":"you\\'re",`

And this is the error: `ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 're","type":"message"`

Answer (score 0):

If your connection to the MariaDB server works in [`ANSI_QUOTES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) mode, double quotes are used to quote identifiers, not strings.

If the connection is in [`NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_backslash_escapes) mode, the backslash is treated as an ordinary character.

The queries `@@GLOBAL.sql_mode` and `@@SESSION.sql_mode` will show the modes.

Also, you don't need to escape single quotes in a double-quoted string in mySQL, nor vice versa. Therefore, if you know before hand how you are going to quote a string before passing it to mySQL, you need only escape one type of quotes; in your case, double quotes.

Instead of escaping a quote with a backslash, you can double it.

Comment: Yeah these are what it says our modes are `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`